# WFFM Unable to use Email Editor in Custom Send Email action

Tags: wffm

I am trying to create a custom WFFM SaveAction that sends an email, and I would like to still use the Email Editor. The problem is, how do I get the information entered through the editor in my custom SaveAction. If I inherit from SendMail, I can't add the SaveAction to the form. I get in the log:

> The constructor parameters may not match or it may be an abstract class.

So I just step back to using ISaveAction, but then I can't access the data from the editor. It seems like I need the IMailSender and IEmailAttributes that SendMail takes, but I can't seem to make that work. How do I access the data from the email editor in a custom SaveAction?

WFFM 8.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide the dependencies in config. For example, the out of the box `Send Email Message` save action has the following definition in Sitecore:

[image: Send Email Definition]

If you check in `Sitecore.WFFM.Dependencies.config` you will find a matching definition:

```
<sitecore>
  <wffm>
    <!--Save actions constructor configuration-->
    <actions>
      ...
      <sendMessage type="Sitecore.WFFM.Actions.SaveActions.SendMessage, Sitecore.WFFM.Actions">
        <param name="settings" ref="/sitecore/wffm/settings" />
        <param name="mailSender" ref="/sitecore/wffm/mailSender" />
      </sendMessage>
      ...
    </actions>
  </wffm>
</sitecore>
```

If you create a custom save action then create a duplicate of this node and change the `type` to your own implementation and change the `Factory Object Name` to point to your new config node.